# C++ file extension in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

GNU GCC compiler will compile c++ source files with both `.C` and`.cpp` extension.

Is it possible to configure Microsoft Visual Studio so that it could compile the c++ source and header files with extensions `.C` and `.H` extension respectively?

Answer (score 4):

The command line option [`/TP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/032xwy55.aspx) tells the compiler to treat the source files as C++, even if the extension is something like `.c`.

In the IDE, you can set this as one of the project properties.  Under C/C++, select Advanced Options and set the "Compile As" fields to C++.

Comment: Does that command line option tell the MVS compiler to treat the source files with `.C` extension  as c++ ?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the Windows file system is not case-sensitive, so there's no difference between .c and .C. This means that the default C language for .c will always apply.

You cannot tell the compiler to generally treat .C files as C++, however you can tell it to treat files in a a compilation command as C++ regardless of their extension with the /TP switch.

Comment: Does that mean it is impossible to compile with `.C` extension in MVS?

Comment: It's possible, but you have to override the compiler default by setting every file to C++ in the project options.